Cannot upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04 from 22.04.5?
I tried to upgrade to the newest Ubuntu (as the system suggested by pop up message).
But during the upgrade (close to the beginning) I got the following error:
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.,
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.,
W:GPG error: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A2F683C52980AECF,
E:The repository 'https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy InRelease' is not signed.

How can I solve this?

I don't have a 22.04 system on hand to confirm nor a virtualbox install. But could you try disabling the repo , or  adding back the keys as per the instructions on https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads before upgrading?

The GPG key error is very common. Have you attempted any of the known fixes to that problem?

According to this post on the official VirtualBox site, you can solve the NO_PUBKEY A2F683C52980AECF error by running this wget command:
wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -

